# assign form inputs to variable

Tags: php, input, concatenation

I have two inputs

```
<input  id=view-title >
<textarea1 id=textarea1 ></textarea>
```

they both got value by this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById("view-title").value = "variable value";
    document.getElementById("textarea1").innerHTML = "variable value";
 </script>
```

is it possible to put those two inputs on a variable?

I've tried this but got error on displaying

```
$variable = '<input  id=view-title >'.'<textarea1 id=textarea1 ></textarea>';
```

Comment: The question seems little unclear. What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

your code

```
<textarea1 ...
```

incorrect, use

```
<textarea ..
```

.

**Correct**

```
$variable = "<input  id='view-title' name='view-title' /><textarea id='textarea1' name='textarea1'></textarea>";
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may given a name to the inputs also;

```
$variable = '<input id="view-title" name="view-title" /><textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1"></textarea>';
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score -1):

yes but you need to `echo $variable;`